# Net::Telnet Error Handling

Tags: perl, error-handling, telnet

Im trying to print "Error IP USER PASS Failed!", on failure.

When i use my script

```
    use Net::Telnet ();
my $t = new Net::Telnet Timeout => 30,
Prompt => '/[\$#%:><][\s\b]+$/';
$t->open($ARGV[0]);
my $user = $ARGV[1];
my $pass = $ARGV[2];

        print "Logging In...\n";
        print "Sending Username....\n";
        $t->print($user);
                $t->waitfor('/[:>%\$#]/');
        print "Sending Password....\n";
        $t->print($pass);
                $t->waitfor('/[:>%\$#]/');

 if ($t->errmsg){
               print "errmsg: " . $t->errmsg . "\n";
        } else {
               print"success\n";
        }
```

The issue:

I know the IP and username: admin and admin are working.

```
root@localhost:~/tel# perl t2.pl *.*.*.* admin admin
Logging In...
Sending Username....
Sending Password....
success
```

Now using a NON working user and pass i get the same "success"

```
root@localhost:~/tel# perl t2.pl 36.85.134.191 admin admi1
Logging In...
Sending Username....
Sending Password....
success
```

What am i doing wrong with the if statement, something is not working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably enable debugging, but I guess that your expectation for the result of passwort matches not only the prompt (e.g. `$` or `#`) but also the username prompt you get if the password was wrong (`:`).